# What is recommended for handling messages for team collaboration

Tags: database, jsf, message, james

Am working on a JSF social media project that allows for collaboration among users. Am thinking of using an email system where all members would receive and send messages within the portal. Should i store the messages in a database or an email system like Apache James?

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Apache James is not a mail storage agent. It is Mail Enterprise Server that processes mails. Read more about the functionality of James [here](http://james.apache.org/).

To answer your question, you can do it either way but it totally depends on how you are going to store your email (MIME/text/custom). Apache James provides you with the functionality to save emails in database or file system or in both database (email headers) and file system (email body).

If this answer didn't help you, give me the scope of your problem with which I can suggest you something viable.

Comment: Questions like this do not belong on stackoverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and the related links on the right if you are on that article